# NSOperationQueue and NSOperation, do I have to release it?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

In the documentation I have read that I don't need to release the NSOperation object because it will be released by the NSOperationQueue, but the instruments gives me a memory leak if I don't release it in some cases, in other cases it crashes if I release. What's the problem what do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have to release your copy that you created.**

I assume that you are doing something like:

`SomeOperation` is subclass of `NSOperation` which does something.

```
- (void)start
{
    SomeOperation *so = [[SomeOperation alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [queue addOperation:so];
    [so release];
}
```

[Apple spec](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperation:):

> addOperation:
>
> ...
>
> operation
>
> The operation object to be
>   added to the queue. In memory-managed
>   applications, this object is retained
>   by the operation queue. In
>   garbage-collected applications, the
>   queue strongly references the
>   operation object.
>
> Once added, the specified operation remains in the queue until it finishes executing.

Comment: Yes, I am doin the same code. So it needs to be released, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, it works with release and you have right. :)
Thanks a lot.